# Cannot create a SQLite connection in a background task under Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, sqlite, windows-phone-8.1, background-task

I am working on a Windows Phone 8.1 app and I have some trouble with the SQLite version in a background task. The following code works without any problem in a Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight App, but if I run it in a background task, it doesn't work.

Debugger says "Database xxx (CanNotopen)".

The code is quite simple.

```
 SQLiteConnection connection = new SQLiteConnection(Constants.DATABASE_PATH, true);
```

Is it necessary to use an absolute path in background tasks?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve it, use [SQLite.Net PCL](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SQLite.Net-PCL/) and the problem is solved!